# Spring Boot Passing Comments Sub Comments

Tags: java, maven, model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having trouble figuring out how I pass my comments and sub comments to my page

So I need to pass out N row_comment & also N row_sub_comment(for each comment)

As example we could have 4 commenst of my review
1st comment with 16 sub comments
2nd comment with 6 sub comments
3rd comment with 26 sub comments
4th comment with 3 sub comments

My java needs to pull them from database and use model.AddAttribute to pass them out

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(Model model) {

    if (content_comment_status == true)
    {
    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

        sql =   "SELECT preview_comment_text, preview_Comment_id
                 FROM preview_comment
                 WHERE preview_id = 4;";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            sub_preview_comment_id = rs.getString("preview_comment_id");
            preview_comment_text = rs.getString("preview_comment_text");                
                try {

                     // 
                    connection = getConnection();
                    stmt = connection.createStatement();

                    sql =   "SELECT sub_preview_comment_text,                       sub_preview_comment_id
                             FROM sub_preview_comment
                             WHERE preview_comment_id = from_outside;";

                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    sb = new StringBuffer();
                    while (rs.next()) { 
                        sub_comment_text = rs.getString("sub_comment_text ");
                        sub_comment_id = rs.getString("sub_comment_id");

                    }
                    stmt.close();
                    connection.close();
                }catch(Exception e) {return e.toString();}
        }
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(Exception e) {return e.toString();}
    }

model.addAttribute{"stuff", java_variables}
I have to pass out N comments and N sub comments somehow

return home;
}
```

I have three tables called "review", "comments" and "sub_comments"
I have so far got the review printed printed to the page using the method above. But a review may have comments and each comment may even have sub comments

How can these at varied amounts be passed to home page 
I am aware of such examples as this

HTML HTML PAGE HTML PAGE

```
<tr th:each="comment: ${comment}">
    <td></td>
    <td th:text="${comment.comment_text}" ></td>
    <td th:text="${comment.username}" ></td>
              <table>
               and also N sub comments need to come oput,,, like in a blob where we have comments and sub commenst
               for each comment
              </table>
</tr>
</table>
```

OR

```
for(i = 0; i <= comments_count; i++)
{
print out comment;
for(i = 0; i <= sub_comments_count; i++)
{
printout our sub comments for this comment above
}
}
```

Comment: Note that `${comment}` references your list of comments, while `commentZ` is an individual comment, see [the Thymeleaf tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach)

Comment: I would relate a comment to its subcomments in your Comment entity, then in the Thymeleaf template, loop over the subcomments, e.g. `<td th:each="subComment : ${commentZ.subComments}">...</td>`

Comment: Ok I don't think I understand what you mean. I have tried. I'm gonna make my question a little cleaer

Comment: Reading theyleaf link you shared now

Comment: Yikes! Use [Spring Data](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) to connect to your database, not plain JDBC. Also definitely never place this code in your controller, it leads to an unholy mess.

Comment: Ok im gonna have a look at spring data , check it out... 
Does it make all this easier?
Thanks :)

Comment: Create 2 Classes `Comment` and `SubComment`. Each `Comment` class contains a `List<SubComment>` Then return the `List<Comment>`

Comment: @DanielGadd please upvote the answer if it helped answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to think for a bit how to answer this, and I think what you need is to take a deep breath and do some reading.

You need to understand the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architectural pattern. You are using the `C` as evidenced by your use of a Spring controller with a `@RequestMapping` annotation, you're using the `V` as evidenced by your use of Thymeleaf. You're using the `M` as evidenced by your use of a Spring `Model` object that you're assigning attributes to, but you're not using the model in the way most of us would. You should be using [Spring Data](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) to connect to and manage your data. Implicit in this is the use of a plain Java object as a place to put a row from a table (these are variously called `POJO` or `entity` objects). [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tools handle the task of mapping between a table row and an `entity` object. Spring Data uses tools like these, for example Hibernate.

So, you'd have a Review `entity` (into which you place rows from your reviews table), and a Comment `entity` (into which you place rows from your comments table), including any comments on a comment (subcomment).

A `Review` would contain a bunch of properties, including a list of `Comment` entities. A `Comment` would contain a list of child comments.

At this point, you can use Thymeleaf to loop over a list of `Review` entities to access its top-level `Comment` entities. For each `Comment` entity, you'd then loop over child `Comment`s. The bit in between, you'll have to do for yourself.

Comment: So i need to read up on spring data and swap that for JDCB ?
My schema is Review, Article, Preview, ... I need to pick a random 1 row from any 1 of the tables. Lets say it lands of review, row 6. So then i have review_comment table and review_comment_sub table. Will need to pull all data from the review row, pull all comments for that row, and all sub comments for each comment.. Can i do this with spring data

Comment: Ben would you be interested in doing a little paid work ? A day or so ?

Comment: Lets chat elsewhere. DM me through my twitter account.

Comment: Follow me back on twitter